# Umbraco flow in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco

Can anybody help me to understand umbraco flow in .NET? I don't know how umbraco handles redirection.

Root of my project contains `default.aspx` file with below contents:

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="default.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="umbraco.UmbracoDefault" trace="true" validateRequest="false" %>
```

Can someone help me to understand its flow in .NET? How are redirections handled by umbraco?

Comment: What's your *actual* question? Why do you want to know about redirection, or assume that Umbraco changes how ASP.NET or HTTP work? Besides, the snippet you posted comes from WebForms which Umbraco abandoned in v8. It doesn't affect redirection.

Comment: Is your real question about *authentication* perhaps? How an unauthenticated request gets redirected to a authentication provider or page, then back to the original page? This is completely different from what you asked, depends on the actual version of Umbraco and again, shouldn't be a concern because it's handled automatically. You don't handle authentication or authorization by trying to modify redirection.

Comment: Maybe the routing section can help: https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/implementation/default-routing